# How to access meridiem of a time in Python?

Tags: python

I have a problem in accessing the meridiem part of time using Python.

Consider this code in python:-

```
import datetime
time = input("Enter the time : (HH:MM:AM/PM)")
# the above time is in string format so to make it in datetime.datetime type
# we need to use strptime function.
time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%H:%M:%p")
# now to access different parts of variable time:-
print(time.hour)  # to access hour
print(time.minute)  # to access minute
```

But I don't know how to check whether the user entered AM or PM.
Try to help

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following session with the interpreter:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strptime('9:00 AM', '%I:%M %p')
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=9, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> time.strptime('9:00 PM', '%I:%M %p')
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=21, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```

If you want to find out if it is AM or PM, you could use the following:

```
>>> get_meridiem = lambda tm: 'AM' if tm.tm_hour < 12 else 'PM'
>>> get_meridiem(time.strptime('9:00 AM', '%I:%M %p'))
'AM'
>>> get_meridiem(time.strptime('9:00 PM', '%I:%M %p'))
'PM'
>>> get_meridiem(time.strptime('12:00 PM', '%I:%M %p'))
'PM'
>>> get_meridiem(time.strptime('11:59 AM', '%I:%M %p'))
'AM'
```

Answer (score 1):

`time.hour` returns the hour as a 24H value (0-23). So if the hour value is lower than 12 it's AM, otherwise PM.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `%H` in

```
time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%H:%M:%p")
```

`%H`  is for 24 hour time format. Whereas the time string that you are parsing is in 12 hour time format, so, you should use `%I` instead for 12 hour format.

```
time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%I:%M:%p")
```

`strptime` probably ignores meridiem when you parse hours as 24 hour time format.

Answer (score 1):

You are quite close, and only need to apply the reverse to strptime.

```
amorpm = time.strftime("%p")
print(amorpm)
```